# Twitter card meta tags work in index.html, not in React Helmet

Tags: reactjs, twitter-card, react-helmet

I have used below React Helmet code in App.js for rending Twitter card meta.

```
          <Helmet>
              <meta charSet="utf-8" />
              <title>
                {`xxxxx`}
              </title>
              <meta
                name="description"
                content={`xxxxx.`}
              />
              <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
              <meta
                name="twitter:title"
                content="xxxxx"
              />
              <meta
                name="twitter:description"
                content="xxxx."
              />
              <meta name="twitter:site" content="@xxxx" />
              <meta
                name="twitter:image"
                content="https:xxxx"
              />
              <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@xxxx" />
            </Helmet>
```

The meta tags do show up while I do a browser inspect. But in twitter card validator(https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), I am getting **ERROR: No card found (Card error).**

**If I add the same meta tags in index.html, it works.** But, I would like the twitter card to work in Helmet so that I can change it dynamically. Is it possible without Server-Side Rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook/Twitter/etc. crawlers do not render JavaScript, so unless you are rendering Helmet content on the server OR including the card meta tags in the index.html file, they will never pick up your client-side updates.

Comment: I believe this is now outdated, as we're successfully using React Helmet on one of our sites and Twitter is correctly picking up the metatags we're adding. See my answer on this same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536778/5464605

Answer (score 1):

Twitter now appears to be rendering JavaScript when crawling webpages for meta tags! At least as far as React Helmet is concerned.

We're using Twitter's `summary_large_image` along with `twitter:image` via Helmet on our React website and it's confirmed working in [the Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) and in live Twitter posts!

*Please note that a URL protocol (https://) was required for Twitter to use the image specified in our `twitter:image` meta tags. We originally had those meta tags built without the URL protocol, and images were not being pulled in by Twitter to display with the tweet.*

Comment: It does not work.
https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/374#issuecomment-848645518

Comment: @MirAshif thanks for linking to that relevant GitHub thread! Not sure why it didn't work with your prototype, because it's working across our entire site where we're using react-helmet without server-side rendering. Here's a Twitter article on troubleshooting cards: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/troubleshooting-cards
Hope that helps!

Comment: Any update on why this is working for some and not others?

Comment: It's not working for me either. Try `https://devbies.ml` and you get a nice preview, but when you try a route such as `https://devbies.ml/categories/remote-jobs`, Twitter card validator complains that it couldn't generate the preview.