# How to show meta tags in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta-tags

I am using React version 16.14.0 and Helmet plugin to dynamically render the meta tags

```
<meta property="og:url" content="..." data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="..." data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="title" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="description" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:title" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:description" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image" content="..." data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Test Project 1" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="..." data-react-helmet="true">
```

I am getting all the tags in the  element, but I cannot see the cards generated by these meta-tags when I try to scrap. I see one solution by using the Server Side Rendering but is there any way to scrap using the client side rendering?

Comment: You shouldn't have to implement server side rendering in order for the cards to be generated. All you need to ensure is that the valid meta tags are present in the html response of your website url. 
I have noticed Helmet misnaming the parameters which might be causing the issue.
What is your website ? The url might help.

Comment: The parameters are set correctly. I don't think there is an issue there.

Comment: What is your website url ?

Answer (score 2):

The page you have pointed shows the following meta tags in it.

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" data-react-helmet="true">
```

However, it was supposed to be

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" data-react-helmet="true">
```

Replace all the `property` to `name` and try it again.

For further info, refer this [Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image).

Comment: Does this will fix social media share issue?
@Nisanth

Comment: Replacing `property` to `name` didn't solve this issue. You can check  the website https://06f96fc2079e.ngrok.io/showcases/test-project-1

Comment: @MohitChandani I am unable to open the url. could you send the correct one.

Comment: https://5d41fd330372.ngrok.io/showcases/test-project-1 try this one @NisanthReddy

Comment: @chaitanyagupta Each social media has it's own tag names. So I would suggest you to follow the documentation for each of the required social medias.

Comment: @MohitChandani Getting "Too Many Connections" error.

Comment: @NisanthReddy can you please check now?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Seems like it is not possible without SSR if you don't put your tags in index.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222217/twitter-card-meta-tags-work-in-index-html-not-in-react-helmet

Comment: We put our meta tags in details page for example detail page of a particular blog and it will vary according to different blogs
@NisanthReddy

Comment: The tags are generated dynamically based on each item clicked. So, how should I dynamically add the tags in index.html

Comment: @MohitChandani Then seems like SSR is the only way.